# Split string and extract variables with shell script

Tags: shell, kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

## Question

Given this single-line string:

```
PG_USER=postgres PG_PORT=1234 PG_PASS=icontain=and*symbols
```

What would be the right way to assign each value to its designated variable so that I can use it afterward?

---

## Context

I'm parsing the context of a k8s secret within a `CronJob` so that I can periodically call a Stored Procedure in our Postgres database.

To do so, I plan on using:

```sh
PG_OUTPUT_VALUE=$(PGPASSWORD=$PG_PASSWD psql -qtAX -h $PG_HOST -p $PG_PORT -U $PG_USER -d $PG_DATABASE -c $PG_TR_CLEANUP_QUERY)

echo $PG_OUTPUT_VALUE
```

The actual entire helm chart I'm currently trying to fix looks like this:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-tr-cleanup-cronjob
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: postgres
            secret:
              secretName: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-postgres
          containers:
          - name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-tr-cleanup-pod
            image: postgres:12-alpine
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            env:
              - name: PG_PROPS
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-postgres
                    key: postgres.properties
            command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - echo "props:" && echo $PG_PROPS && PG_USER=$(grep "^PG_USER=" | cut -d"=" -f2-) && echo $PG_USER && PG_TR_CLEANUP_QUERY="SELECT something FROM public.somewhere;" && echo $PG_TR_CLEANUP_QUERY && PG_OUTPUT_VALUE=$(PGPASSWORD=$PG_PASSWD psql -qtAX -h $PG_HOST -p $PG_PORT -U $PG_USER -d $PG_DATABASE -c $PG_TR_CLEANUP_QUERY) && echo PG_OUTPUT_VALUE
            volumeMounts:
              - name: postgres
                mountPath: /etc/secrets/postgres
```

#### Current approach

As you can see, I'm currently using:

```sh
PG_USER=$(grep "^PG_USER=" | cut -d"=" -f2-)
```

That is because I initially thought the secret would be output on multiple lines, but it turns out that I was wrong. The `echo $PG_USER` displays an empty string.

Comment: Your `grep` is wrong. What is the input to grep command ?

Comment: You are right, I should've piped an `echo` as the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

This function can be reused to assign each variable individually:

```sh
extract() {
  echo "$INPUT" | grep -o "$1=.*" | cut -d" " -f1 | cut -d"=" -f2- ;
}
```

And to use it:

```sh
PG_USER=$(extract PG_USER)
PG_PORT=$(extract PG_PORT)
PG_PASS=$(extract PG_PASS)
```

---

## Option 2

Another potential solution, **with a security concern**, is to simply use:

```sh
eval "$INPUT"
```

It should only be used if you have validated the input.

---

## Contextual complete answer

And because I've presented the k8s context in the question, here is the answer as plugged into that solution.

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-cronjob
spec:
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          volumes:
          - name: postgres
            secret:
              secretName: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-postgres
          containers:
          - name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-cronjob-pod
            image: postgres:12-alpine
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            env:
              - name: PG_PROPS
                valueFrom:
                  secretKeyRef:
                    name: {{ template "fullname" $ }}-postgres
                    key: postgres.properties
            command:
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - >-
                extract() { echo "$PG_PROPS" | grep -o "$1=.*" | cut -d" " -f1 | cut -d"=" -f2- ; } &&

                export PGHOST=$(extract PG_HOST) &&
                export PGPORT=$(extract PG_PORT) &&
                export PGDATABASE=$(extract PG_DATABASE) &&
                export PGUSER=$(extract PG_USER) &&

                PG_SCHEMA=$(extract PG_SCHEMA) &&
                PG_QUERY="SELECT tenant_schema FROM $PG_SCHEMA.tenant_schema_mappings;" &&

                PGPASSWORD=$(extract PG_PASSWD) psql --echo-all -c "$PG_QUERY"
            volumeMounts:
              - name: postgres
                mountPath: /etc/secrets/postgres
```

Answer (score 1):

The bash `declare` command is appropriate here, and is safer than `eval`.

Suppose the input contains something potentially malicious

```sh
line='PG_USER=postgres PG_PORT=1234 PG_PASS=icontain=and*symbols`ls`'
```

I'm assuming none of the values contain whitespace. Let's split that string

```sh
read -ra assignments <<< "$line"
```

Now, `declare` each one

```sh
for assignment in "${assignments[@]}"; do declare "$assignment"; done
```

Everywhere we examine the input, we maintain double quotes.

Let's see what we ended up with:

```sh
$ declare -p PG_USER PG_PORT PG_PASS
declare -- PG_USER="postgres"
declare -- PG_PORT="1234"
declare -- PG_PASS="icontain=and*symbols\`ls\`"
```